# Inserting nodes at the beginning

Tags: c

I am working on a code that will take 3 airport codes and turn them into nodes, then add them to the list. Here is what I have so far:

```
void insertFirst(AirportCode code, Node **listPtr) {
    /* IMPLEMENT */
    //needs to add code to list, then change the head pointer
    Node* head;
    head = NULL;
    char tarray[4];
    strncpy(tarray, code, 4);
    Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->airport = tarray;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

/* defined types:
   AirportCode is an alias for a 4-char array
   Node is a linked list node (struct) for AirportCodes */
typedef char AirportCode[4];
typedef struct node {
    AirportCode airport;
    struct node *next;
} Node;
```

The following part CANNOT be changed:

```
/* newNode - here is a utility function to create a new node;
    node's airport set to a copy of code, and next set to NULL;
     returns a pointer to the new node */
Node *newNode(AirportCode code) {
    Node *node;
    if ((node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node))) != NULL) {
        strcpy(node->airport, code);
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory - terminating\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return node;
}
```

Everytime I try to compile this using gcc I get the error:

> array type 'AirportCode' (aka 'char [4]') is not
>         assignable
>   I have no idea why this is happening, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't "assign" to an array in C. You could use [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy), or `strcpy()`, but in the end the code is only 4 chars wide. hard code the 4 elements one-by-one as assignments : `temp->airport[0] = tarray[0]; temp->airport[1] = tarray[1];` etc... And [`strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) likely doesn't work the way you may think, so review *exactly* what it does. Finally, your first-insert function *doesn't*. It never touches the passed in `listPtr`, and thus leaks memory and never updates your list.

Comment: And pick a language. I see no C++ standard library or language specific features in this at all. If this is C, drop the C++ tag.

Comment: Assuming this is strictly c code and not c++, you could typedef char *AirportCode and then have your init function for creating AirportCodes malloc 4 chars, but is this c or c++?

Comment: This is C. I didnt mean to add the C++ tag. How would I change this to implement the listPtr? @WhozCraig

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign char arrays to each other like that (and even if you could, it would not have the result I believe you are expecting). I suppose what you want to do is string assigment? Then, given that you use C++, you should define AirportCode as a `std::string` rather than a `char[4]`.

Comment: But if it is only C (as stated in your comment), then you can't use `std::string` but should rather use `strncpy` or a hard-coded byte-by-byte copy as suggested by WhozCraig.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
void insertFirst(AirportCode code, Node **listPtr) {
    Node* head = *listPtr;
    Node* temp = newNode(code);
    temp->next = head;
    *listPtr = temp;
}
```